# Camel Aggregator forceCompletionOnStop VS completeAllOnStop

Tags: apache-camel, aggregator

What's the différence between forceCompletionOnStop  and completeAllOnStop ? it is possible or recommanded to use both togheter ?

From the documentation:

> **forceCompletionOnStop** Indicates to complete all current aggregated exchanges when the context is stopped
>
> **completeAllOnStop** Indicates to wait to complete all current and partial (pending) aggregated exchanges when the context is stopped. This also means that we will wait for all pending exchanges which are stored in the aggregation repository to complete so the repository is empty before we can stop. You may want to enable this when using the memory based aggregation repository that is memory based only, and do not store data on disk. When this option is enabled, then the aggregator is waiting to complete all those exchanges before its stopped, when stopping CamelContext or the route using it.

Its little confusing for me it seems to be the same

Answer (score 1):

**`completeAllOnStop`** is a "normal" completion criteria. The Camel aggregator implements the `ShutdownAware` interface and the `completeAllOnStop` criteria indicates to the Camel context that the aggregator needs **some extra time before shutdown** to complete its aggregations.

**`forceCompletionOnStop`** on the other hand tries to complete all aggregations **during the shutdown process** (`prepareShutdown`).

So to me they seem very similar too, both are trying to complete all aggregations before shutdown of the Camel context. I would recommend to use **`completeAllOnStop`** because this seems to be the more proactive way. See also the [Camel Docs for more info about the shutdown strategy](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html).

I don't know if you get a "double check" if you configure them both :-)

> Be aware that **even `forceCompletionOnStop` is skipped** if the shutdown is a **forced shutdown**! In this case Camel tries to shutdown as fast as possible. 
>   As far as I know Camel does a forced shutdown when the normal shutdown is not successful within a timeout.